# React-router: Maximum Callstack Exceeded

Tags: react

Estou tentando configurar as rotas para minha aplicação porém quando me baseio no [exemplo oficial no github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-with-shared-root/config/routes.js) me aparece um error de `"Maximum Callstack Exceeded"`.

Eu verifiquei tudo ponto a ponto e não consigo encontrar o meu erro.

Segue o meu código:

`routes.js`

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import auth from './auth';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

// Global
import AppContainer from '../components/App';

// Login
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';

//Dashboard
import DashboardContainer from '../components/Dashboard';

// Supplier
import SupplierContainer from '../components/Supplier';
import SupplierListContainer from '../components/Supplier/List';


function redirectToLogin(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathName: nextState.location.pathname }
    });
  }
}

function redirectToDashboard(nextState, replace) {
  if (auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace('/');
  }
}

export const routes =  (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
      <IndexRoute component={DashboardContainer}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} onEnter={redirectToLogin} />
      <Route path="supplier" component={SupplierContainer}>
          <IndexRoute component={SupplierListContainer}/>
          <Route path="list" component={SupplierListContainer}/>
        </Route>
      <Route path="login" component={LoginForm} onEnter={redirectToDashboard} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

`index.js`

```
'use script';

// React
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './utils/storage/store';
import { routes } from './utils/routes';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Alguém tem uma idéia do que está acontecendo?

Agradeço desde já

Comment: `export const routes =  (`? isso exporta `undefined`. Talvez queiras `export default {routes: (` ?

Comment: O estranho é que ele reconhece as rotas... o problema acontece na chamada do método `redirectToLogin` que é chamada diversas vezes seguidas... vou tentar aplicar sua sugestão e ver se isso ajuda em algo mesmo assim. Obrigado

Comment: Onde tens `import {auth} ...` ?

Comment: dentro do próprio arquivo `routes.js`

Comment: Ok, como não está(va) na pergunta achei estranho

Comment: Editei a resposta com as importações

Comment: Acho que deves ter `render((<Provider store={store}>
    routes={routes}
  </Provider>),
  document.getElementById('app')
);` no index.js e um objeto nas routes. Estás a passar JSX para as routes...

Comment: posta também o que vc tem no auth